# C, Read a File, Interpret the file, Output interpretation into new file

Tags: c

I've been struggling to learn how to program in C for weeks now, but I'm at a point where I can't get myself unstuck. My program is supposed to read in a file of four and five band resistor color codes (i.e AGIE) where each letter represents a resistor band color, then using a standard resistor band interpretation chart print the value of the resistor and upper and lower tolerance limits.

As of now, I think I'm correctly reading in my file; however, my function isn't producing any results and I don't know where to go with trying to decipher 4 or 5 bands.

An example input would be: (where 604 is the number of resistor codes in the file)

```
604
CCIF
IJFCJ
CFHJ
BJFG
KIJDJ
EKCC
HABKC
JFID
ECHDA
IJHEB
```

Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void FourBR(char ccode[], long cval[], double rval);
void FiveBR(char ccode[], long cval[], double rval);

int main()
{
//DECLARE VARIABLES AND POINTERS//
char str[604];
char ccode[6];
long cval[6];
int num, i;
double resistorval, rval;
FILE *fpin;
FILE *fpoutpt;

//OPEN FILE//
fpin=fopen("G:\\EGR 107\\EEHW4(AGraff)\\resistorInput.txt", "r");
fpoutpt=fopen("G:\\EGR 107\\EE\\EEHW4(AGraff)\\resistorOutput.txt", "w");

//ERROR CHECK//
if(fpin==NULL)
{
    printf("Error reading file.\n");
    exit (0);
}
fscanf(fpin, "%d", &num);
printf("# of Resistors: %d\n", num);

while((fgets (str, 604, fpin))!= NULL) {

FourBR(ccode, cval, rval);
FiveBR(ccode, cval, rval);


fclose(fpin);

return 0;
}


void FourBR(char ccode[], long cval[], double rval)
{
int i, j, k, mult;
for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {

    switch (ccode [0]) {
    case('A'):
        cval[0]=0;
    case('B'):
        cval[0]=1;
    case('C'):
        cval[0]=2;
    case('D'):
        cval[0]=3;
    case('E'):
        cval[0]=4;
    case('F'):
        cval[0]=5;
    case('G'):
        cval[0]=6;
    case('H'):
        cval[0]=7;
    case('I'):
        cval[0]=8;
    case('J'):
        cval[0]=9;

    }
}

for(j=0; j<=6; j++)
{
    switch (ccode[1])
    {
    case 'A':
        cval[1]=0;
    case('B'):
        cval[1]=1;
    case('C'):
        cval[1]=2;
    case('D'):
        cval[1]=3;
    case('E'):
        cval[1]=4;
    case('F'):
        cval[1]=5;
    case('G'):
        cval[1]=6;
    case('H'):
        cval[1]=7;
    case('I'):
        cval[1]=8;
    case('J'):
        cval[1]=9;
    }
    }
 for (mult=0; mult<=6; mult++)
 {
    switch (ccode[2])
    {
    case('A'):
        cval[2]=1;
    case('B'):
        cval[2]=10;
    case('C'):
        cval[2]=100;
    case('D'):
        cval[2]=1000;
    case('E'):
        cval[2]=10*pow(10,3);
    case('F'):
        cval[2]=10*pow(10,4);
    case('G'):
        cval[2]=10*pow(10,5);
    case('H'):
        cval[2]=10*pow(10,6);
    case('I'):
        break;
    case('J'):
        break;
    case('K'):
        cval[2]=0.1;
    case('L'):
        cval[2]=0.01;
    }
 }
 for (k=0; k<=6; k++) {
    switch (ccode[3]) {
    case 'A':
        break;
    case('B'):
        cval[3]=0.01;
    case('C'):
        cval[3]=0.02;
    case('D'):
        break;
    case('E'):
        break;
    case('F'):
        cval[3]=0.005;
    case('G'):
        cval[3]=0.0025;
    case('H'):
        cval[3]=0.001;
    case('I'):
        cval[3]=0.0005;
    case('J'):
        break;
    case('K'):
        cval[3]=0.05;
    case('L'):
        cval[3]=0.1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where does ccode gets filled in? In fact where are they declared? You have commented out the declaration

Comment: Post a link to (or a couple of lines) of sample input. That will help provide a complete working example.

Comment: What does the empty `for` loop do? Which line do you think writes anything to the output file `fpoutpt`? I think you've started removing things to debug, and posted that version. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually see the problem.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` does nothing good. Remove it.

Comment: Each `case` without a `break` will fall through to the next `case` - that's probably not behaviour you want here.

Comment: @OllieFord Yes, i ended up removing the for loop completely. I left the FiveBR resistor function out of this new code because it adds ALOT of extra space. There's probably a much more efficient way to do this, I just don't know it.

Comment: What's the point of these loops like `for (mult=0; mult<=6; mult++)`?

Comment: Where do you print the result of the conversions?  Why do you call both `FourBR` and `FiveBR`; you can tell whether it is a 4-band or 5-band resistor and call just the correct one, can't you?  Don't forget that `fgets()` keeps the newline when it reads a line.  Note that `cval[]` is an array of `long`; it can only store `0.1` and `0.01` as `0`, which isn't what you want.

Comment: You're reading data into `str` and not passing it to your functions, so it isn't surprising they don't decode it properly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Would it be best to decide which to call using an if statement? Also I completely missed the cval[] data type mistake. Thank you!

Comment: I would expect to use an `if` statement based on the length of the string to decide which function to call.  I'd also aim to use one or two tables of colour codes rather than writing out a multiple case statements.  I agree with the question "why the 6-step `for` loops", too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I was trying to leave enough space in my loop to include the potential 5 characters but also the \n.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that I don't fully understand your color mapping code scheme, I think the following will help you with your project. For purposes of the code below, I let `A-J` provide the mapping of `0-9` on the resistor chart to show you an approach to mapping codes to resistor values. (if the input code contains a `'K'` or above, it is kicked out -- you can fill in that logic)

**Note:** the code below simply provides a mapping for the significant figure color bands (band/chars 1 & 2 for 4-band, and 1, 2 & 3 for 5-band resistors). The significant figure value is multiplied by the **multiplier** (band 3 in 4-band, and band 4 in 5-band resistors) to arrive at a resitor value. (the tolerance is ignored).

One of the first things you will need to do in any project is get a handle on the range of values you will be dealing with in order to choose what data type will adequately hold the values while not wasting memory needlessly. Looking at your input, you will be reading string of up to 5 characters. **note**, the line ending in the file `'\n'` is also a character that `fgets` will try to read, **and** you need room for a `null-terminating` charcter `'\0'` at the end. So your **minimum string size** for reading your input file is `7`. (While you can get away with the minimum, it is wise to add a couple additional characters in case you port the code to dos and have `'\r\n'` line endings to deal with, or there is a stray char or two in the file). A reasonabe choice is in the `9-10` range. Now instead of hardcoding `10` throughout your code, make use of a `#define` to set this value once at the beginning of your file. (e.g. `#define LMAX 10` -- with no semi-colon for your 'line max'). You can easily adjust the value in the future if you need.

The same logic applies to the rest of your variables. As a rule of thumb, if the range includes both positive and negative values, choose `int` or `long`. If the values will always be positive, choose `size_t` or `unsigned`, etc.. It helps to keep a quick reference handy:

```
 data type sizes for x86_64:

  sizeof (char)      : 1
  sizeof (char*)     : 8  (all pointers)
  sizeof (short)     : 2
  sizeof (int)       : 4
  sizeof (long)      : 8
  sizeof (long long) : 8

 data type storage sizes for x86_64:

  char - signed       :        -128  to  127
  char - unsigned     :           0  to  255
  short - signed      :      -32768  to  32767
  short - unsigned    :           0  to  65535
  int - signed        : -2147483648  to  2147483647
  int - unsigned**    :           0  to  4294967295
  (l)long - signed    : -9.2234e+18  to  9.2234e+18
  (l)long - unsigned  :           0  to  1.8447e+19  18446744073709551613

  ** size_t is an unsigned int for practical purposes
```

After choosing your types, and choosing variable names, remember to **always initialize your variable to a value!** Attempting to read from an unitialized variable is **Undefined Behavior** and is the bane of beginning C programmers.

Next, you need to get information in/out of your program. In your case you need both input and output filenames. You can always prompt for, and read the variables, but it is far easier, and generally accepted, to pass the information your code needs to run -- as arguments to your program. (i.e. through `argv[1], argv[2], ...`) Simply use `int main (int argc, char **argv)`, and you have an array of strings that are the arguments to your code in `argv` (argv[0] is always the program name used to run the program). When you pass arguments in/out of your code or to functions within your code, **verify/validate** the input.

For your resistor program, (and any program), you make life easier on yourself by thinking through what you need your code to do -- before you start pecking away. Input, processing and output. (i.e., get filenames, open input/output files, get string input, validate, strip trailing newlines, read individual band characters, read multiplier, convert significant figures to numbers, convert multiplier to number, multiply to get resistor value, etc..) Doing this upfront saves enormous amounts of time. It provides a roadmap for you to follow, and it allows you to identify similar/repetitive tasks to split into functions for repeated use.

You already had the file opening, you had the file read (who knows where `308` came from), and you started tinkering with an approach to conversion, but that is pretty much where the wheels fell off. In your function, you understood that you needed to look at each character and map the character value to a number, but you got hung up on what needed a `numeric` (decimal) value and what needed to be a `character` value? (that just takes learning and paying close attention too)

Getting the resistor value from the string input isn't too difficult. If you have limited the number of input characters to `5` (a 5-band max), then you know that your significant figure bands will be characters between `0 < (length-2)` for both 4 & 5-band resistors. Your approach with a `switch statement` was fine, but there are a couple of tricks that help.

For the multiplier, you know that will always be the next to last character (band) in the string. (at `string[length-2]`)

Instead of using a `switch` for the significant figure conversion, take a look at the [[**ASCII Table and Descriptions**]](http://www.asciitable.com/). Note that character `'A'` has an ASCII value of `65` and `'J'` a value of `74`. You can use the difference between the character values to convert the letters to character numerals by adding the difference to character `'0'(48)`. (i.e. `'G'(71) - 'A'(65) = 6` -- `'0'(48) + 6 = 54` [character `'6'`]) You want each value in your converted string to have the **character value** for the digit. (e.g. **not** the decimal value `6`). Note the subtle difference from what your `switch` statement was doing. (it was assigning the decimal, not the character value to `cval[x]`-- to fix it, you must quote your numbers). Unless you are going to manually convert (the `cval` array in your case) to a number, then all the conversion routines `atoi, strtol, etc..` expect to receive a string full of **character values** to convert, not a string of decimals.

To find the multiplier, you can do the **almost** the same thing, **except** this time you **do** want the decimal value as you will be using that value directly without calling a conversion routine. Here you can find the multiplier places value by simply taking the difference between the characters and raising `10` to that power. (no need for the math library, a quick loop will do) Choosing an intial value for your multiplier variable of `1` allows you to quickly compute the multiplier once you translate the band to a value. A simple loop that multiplies your multiplier value by 10 the number of times indicated by the band will suffice.

With all that jabber, which turned out to be much longer than I had originally thought, I put together a quick example illustrating the points. (**note:** I use `ccode` to collect the character digits, then I call the value converted to a number `cval` -- which is opposite from your naming) Also note, the only required argument to the program is the **input** file. If the **output** file is not given, it will simply dump the output to the screen along with the error messages. (handy for development)

Look though the code. Take the time to understand what each part is doing (it is the price you pay to learn), and remember there are probably a dozed different correct ways to approach this problem. None more right than the other as long as they are correct.

You have made the right choice to pursue C. There is no other high-level language that provides the flexibility and control that C does. However, with that level of flexibility and control, comes the responsibility to learn how to use it correctly. There are a lot of good people here that can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for strtol   */
#include <string.h>     /* for strlen   */
#include <errno.h>      /* for errno    */

#define LMAX 10

unsigned long resistor_val (char *s, unsigned char len);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s infile [outfile]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char str[LMAX] = {0};           /* input buffer (LMAX-1 chars)  */
    FILE *ifp = NULL;               /* input file pointer           */
    FILE *ofp = NULL;               /* output file pointer (stdout) */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* line index / counter         */
    size_t nchr = 0;                /* number of chars in str       */
    unsigned long rval = 0;         /* resistor value from ccode    */

    /* open/validate input file */
    if (!(ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* open/validate output file (default: stdout) */
    if (argc > 2) {
        if (!(ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w"))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[2]);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
        ofp = stdout;

    /* read loop - read each line in the input file */
    while (fgets (str, LMAX, ifp) != NULL)
    {
        /* get the length of each string read */
        nchr = strlen (str);

        /* strip CR & LF from each line  */
        while (nchr > 0 && (str[nchr-1] == '\r' || str[nchr-1] == '\n'))
            str [--nchr] = 0;

        /* call resistor_val function, output results (or line if error) */
        if ((rval = resistor_val (str, nchr)))
            fprintf (ofp, " line[%3zu]  code: %-5s  rval: %lu\n", idx, str, rval);
        else
            fprintf (ofp, "*line[%3zu]  code: %-5s\n", idx, str);

        idx++;
    }

    /* close input/output files */
    if (ifp) fclose (ifp);
    if (ofp != stdout)  fclose (ofp);

    return 0;
}

/* read resistor colors presuming 4 or 5 band resistor
   where the last band indicates 'tolerence', and the
   band before it is the 'multiplier'. On success return 
   the ohm value for the resistor before any tolerence 
   or reliability factors are applied, 0 otherwise.
   presumes code values of [A-J] only!
*/
unsigned long resistor_val (char *s, unsigned char len)
{
    char ccode[LMAX] = {0};             /* array to hold numbers    */
    unsigned long cval = 0;             /* converted ccode value    */
    unsigned char idx = 0;              /* ccode index / counter    */
    unsigned char it = 0;               /* loop iterator            */
    unsigned long mult = 1;             /* multiplier for resistor  */

    /* validate input string and length */
    for (it = 0; it < len; it++)
        if ((s[it] < 'A' || s[it] > 'J') {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: argument contains chars outside [A-J] : '%s'.\n", 
                    __func__, s);
            return 0;
        }

    if (len > 5) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: input exceeds 5 characters\n", __func__);
        return 0;
    }

    /* set the numeric value for each resistor value character */
    for (idx = 0; idx < len - 2; idx++)
        ccode[idx] = '0' + s[idx] - 'A';

    /* set the multiplier for the resistor */
    for (it = 0; it < s[len - 2] - 'A'; it++)
        mult *= 10;

    /* convert ccode to a number */
    errno = 0;
    cval = strtoul (ccode, NULL, 10);
    if (errno) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid cval conversion.\n", __func__);
        return 0; 
    }

    /* return multiplier times cval */
    return mult * cval;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o resistors resistors.c
```

You can drop `-g` (generate debugging information) for your final compile, but it is needed if you are going to use the `gdb` debugger. (getting to know `gdb` is a must).

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/resistors dat/resifile.txt dat/resfile.txt
resistor_val() error: argument contains chars outside [A-J] : '604'.
resistor_val() error: argument contains chars outside [A-J] : 'KIJDJ'.
resistor_val() error: argument contains chars outside [A-J] : 'EKCC'.
resistor_val() error: argument contains chars outside [A-J] : 'HABKC'.

$ cat dat/resfile.txt
*line[  0]  code: 604
 line[  1]  code: CCIF   rval: 2200000000
 line[  2]  code: IJFCJ  rval: 89500
 line[  3]  code: CFHJ   rval: 250000000
 line[  4]  code: BJFG   rval: 1900000
*line[  5]  code: KIJDJ
*line[  6]  code: EKCC
*line[  7]  code: HABKC
 line[  8]  code: JFID   rval: 9500000000
 line[  9]  code: ECHDA  rval: 427000
 line[ 10]  code: IJHEB  rval: 8970000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're explanation cleared up SO many things I was confused on.

Comment: Glad I could help. C is just one of those languages that when you are learning, ... sometimes you just need a good push to get over the current roadblock. Keep up the good work. If you get stuck again, just drop a comment, or as another question.